# Handling valid modal dismissals and true exceptions

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ng-bootstrap

In most Angular libraries (and specifically ng-boostrap) there is a way to open modals on the page that block the user from doing anything until they every "close" the modal or "dismiss" the modal.  In ng-bootstrap it looks [like this](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples).

```
try {
    let handle = this.nbgModal.open(...);
    await handle.result;
    // any code here won't run until after the modal is 'closed'
}catch(e){
    // however, if the user 'dismisses' the modal then the catch block is ran
    // so what happens in here if a real exception is thrown???
}
```

The response of the `open(...)` method allows you to use `async/await` keywords to wait for the modal to be interacted with by the user before proceeding to the rest of the code.

If the user "closes" the model, the Promise is resolved and we continue using some result from the modal possibly. However, if the user "dismisses" the modal then we will reject the Promise and the code in the `catch` block will run.

So now the final question... what happens when a *true* exception is thrown in any of the code in the `try` block above?  In this example we would swallow the exception and the user/developer would never know since the console won't emit an error.

Use promises for modal like this has been so methign I've seen for years, so what is the expected solution for determining whether you are dealing with a valid business scenario (e.g. dismissal) vs. an exception that is throw due to a bug?

I have a solution to this but I feel like I would be fighting against these libraries to build another service that does ever reject unless theres a true exception.  Am I missing somethign that should allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't blame the developers of libs. Raising expectation on the promise rejection when using `await` seems doubtful as well.

```
try {
    let handle = this.nbgModal.open(...);
    handle.result
        .then(result=>doSmgWithDialogResult(result))
        .catch(()=>doSmgWhenDialogDIsmnissed());
} catch(e) {
    // catch exceptions
}
```